# How do I get a child of a flex-grow div to have height 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the below example I would expect the `innerContent` div to be the whole height of the content div but it is not:
([plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/HDyLpWKEliQR1ZiTfn9N?p=preview))

```css
.shell{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}

.content{
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.innerContent{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    
    <div class="shell">
      
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
      </div>
      
      <div class="content">
        <div class="innerContent">
          Content
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="footer">
        Footer
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
```

The expected behaviour is that the inner content (blue) is the same height as the content area (red). For me I get this:

[image]

Comment: `innerContent` is the same height as `content` to me?

Comment: its working how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed on chrome 71 by changing `flex-grow: 1;` to `flex: 1;`.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pC3ZDVFihqJ5SFf3d3zv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is bug with Chrome. The behaviour of Flexbox in chrome changed between version 71 and 72 of chrome.

In chrome 72 I get the expected behaviour:

[image]